# When I try to add new fields in objects in Array of objects, code is crashing

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, promise, fetch

**This part works fine before i add fetchViewCounts function**

```
let videosArray = []

function fetchVideos() {
    showLoader(true)
    renderList()
    return fetch(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&order=date&q=${input.value}&key=${api_key}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => response.items.map(item => {
            if (item.id.videoId) {
                videosArray.push({
                    id: item.id.videoId,
                    title: item.snippet.title,
                    channelTitle: item.snippet.channelTitle,
                    description: item.snippet.description || '',
                    publishTime: item.snippet.publishTime,
                    image: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url,
                    viewCount: ''
                })
            }
        }))
        .then(fetchViewCounts)
        .then(renderList)
        // .then(addClickListenersForOpenPlayer)
        // .then(() => showLoader(false))
        // .catch(err => console.log(err))      
}
```

**Then starts a problems**

```
function fetchViewCounts() {
    let newaaray = []
    
    if (videosArray) {
        videosArray.map(item => {
            return fetch(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?&part=statistics&id=${item.id}&maxResults=10&key=${api_key}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                item.viewCount = +data.items[0].statistics.viewCount
                newaaray.push(item)
                return newaaray.sort((a,b) => a.viewCount < b.viewCount ? 1 : -1)
            })
        })
    }
    return newaaray


}

function renderList(content) {
            
    let whatWeSearchValue = input.value

    if (content) {
        console.log(content)
    }
    const html = content
        ? content.map(toCard).join('')
        : `<div class=" text-center text-danger pb-2">Здесь появятся результаты поиска</div>`

    list.innerHTML = html

    if (content) {
        let infoAboutSearch = `<div class=" text-center text-muted"> Результат поиска по запросу <span class="text-danger">${whatWeSearchValue}</span></div>`
        whatWeSearch.classList.remove('invisible')
        whatWeSearch.innerHTML = infoAboutSearch
    }
}

function toCard(video) {
    console.log(video)
    return `
        <div class="row item-card mt-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
                <img class="img m-1 cursor-pointer" src="${video.image}" alt="">
                <span class="text-muted">${video.publishTime}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h5 class="text-primary cursor-pointer title">${video.title}</h5>
                <span class="text-danger mr-2">${video.channelTitle}</span>
                <p class="cursor-pointer">${video.description}</p>
            </div>
            <iframe class="video hidden" width="100%" height="${calcVideoHeight()}"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${video.id}"
            frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen
        >
        </iframe>
        </div>

        <hr>
    `
}
```

**Console log says: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at renderList**

I might consider, something wrong with array which returns from function fetchViewCounts, maybe when i sort the Array.  Help me please understand what i do wrong.

Comment: There are many issues with your code. It will be hard to get an answer that solves all the problems you have. But start by making `fetchViewCounts` return a *promise*, because now it returns an empty array. Then avoid global variables which also are to be populated asynchronously.

Comment: Your sort method sorts arrays in-place. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort. Try sorting in place then returning the `newaaray` variable.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I resolve my problem by wrapping videosArray.map in Promise.all(). Sort method works only in map loop. How can i make code better?